# How to create and control a dialog and a new activity from a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, dialog

I have a trouble with thread, activity and dialog.
This is: I have a HomeUI, RoomUI - that are Activity, and i have a ThreadSocket - that is a Thread.
Now, in HomeUI, i create and run the thread. In ThreadSocket, i linten some messages. With messages A, i create a dialog for HomeUI from ThreadSocket (Dialog include information from A, a button with time decrement to dismiss). With messages B, i finish HomeUI and start RoomUI but, the thread still must alive. I dont know how to do. I try it with handler from HomeUI to the thread, but it error. So? Any one have some idea, how to do that, what do i do?

Comment: Question is not clear . Can you share some code?

Comment: I just want to know the ideas to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try in ThreadSocket something like this:

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     // display and handle dialog 
                    // create intent to RoomUI
                   // finish HomeUI
                }
            });
```